# Galaxy can't boot up, stucked at Samsung logo

Tags: boot-loop

I recently upgraded my stock ROM of my Galaxy GT-p1000 from Froyo 2.2 to Gingerbread 2.3.6 and got stucked. I used the Odin to flash the ROM, it was successful by indicating that the ROM has been flashed OK, it rebooted and hanged at Samsung logo there rebooting & loop back to restart rebooting again over and over. Someone told me something about flashing the boot image with ADB, I do not even know what's ADB talking less of where find. I'm stuck, what should I do for my tab to boot up?

Comment: Have you checked with the first-aid provided in the [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info)? E.g. have you cleared cache, wiped Dalvik, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you have aready use Odin to flash, I think you know how to get these necessary files: Bootloader, PDA, PHONE, CSC, PIT.

Then, let's start.

Force the device to the upload mode by this way: simultaneously press power button and down button.

- When the device is in download mode, plug Odin software and flash ONLY bootloader file (normally bootloader file is like this: BOOTLOADER_DEVICECODE.tar.md5 ).
- After that, flash again with all PDA, Bootloader, CSC, PHONE and it's ok without PIT.
- You should use the lastest version of Odin, as I am now using ver. 3.07.

Please feel free if you need more help.

Comment: Sir, your answer is very close to solving this my problem. I was able to download the latest version of Odin 3.07 but I can't find where to download BOOTLOADER_DEVICECODE.tar.md5. Where can I find this file to download?

Comment: Could it be that P1000XWJQ8 Android 2.3.6 Firmware Rom that I used to Flash/Update the Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 is the wrong one? Everything seem Ok when I flash the Tab, it clearly displayed "PASS" after it was successfully flash. At first when the Bootloop started, I flashed PDA with DBData file. Can you suggest another Firmware ROM for the Galaxy Tab GT-P1000, Jelly Bean 4.0.1, 4.0.4 or something? I really needs your help.

Comment: Again someone suggested that I should flash my Boot Image with ADB, I do not even know what is ADB, do you know anything about ADB? If you please tell me about and where I can get the file

Comment: 1. As I know, normally when something happens with on/off state, it is related to bootloader file. Bootloader file is the most basic ground state for other layers, and apps to boot up.
  
2. Well, I have no idea using ADB, Odin is likely a greatest one to flash device. :)   
3. This might be helpful for you: http://androidromupdate.com/2012/02/26/how-to-install-p1000xwjq8-android-2-3-6-firmware-update-on-galaxy-tab-gt-p1000/